# Swift - UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning not transform as expected with Swift4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I just upgraded to XCode9 with Swift4 today.
And I found that my `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` doesn't work as expected anymore.
The effect of this animation is that the `fromView` will scale down to 0.95 and the `toView` will slide in from the right side. The `pop` operation will do it reversely.
But now when I hit the back button of the NavigationBar, the start position of the `toView` isn't right. It displayed a original size `toView` and then scale up to 1.05.

Here's how I implement the transition animator.

```
// animate a change from one viewcontroller to another
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
    let container = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from)!
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to)!

    // set up from 2D transforms that we'll use in the animation
    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: container.frame.width, y: 0)
    let offScreenDepth = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)

    // start the toView to the right of the screen
    if( presenting ){
        toView.transform = offScreenRight

        container.addSubview(fromView)
        container.addSubview(toView)
    }
    else{
        toView.transform = offScreenDepth

        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(fromView)
    }

    // get the duration of the animation
    // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
    // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
    let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    // perform the animation!
    // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
    // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
    // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        if( self.presenting ){
            fromView.transform = offScreenDepth
        }
        else{
            fromView.transform = offScreenRight
        }

        toView.transform = .identity

    }, completion: { finished in

        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)

    })
}
```

I didn't found anything special in this migration guide page.
https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4/
What should I do to make the transition works again?

Comment: this is much more likely to be an ios11 issue than a swift 4 one

Comment: Maybe. I have no idea why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting anything else, try to reset transformations of the `fromView` to `identity`:

```
// animate a change from one viewcontroller to another
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    ...

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        if( self.presenting ){
            fromView.transform = offScreenDepth
        }
        else{
            fromView.transform = offScreenRight
        }

        toView.transform = .identity

    }, completion: { finished in

        fromView.transform = .identity
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)

    })

    ....
}
```

Comment: Not works. The value of the `transform` seems right. The problems is the displaying. It did transform from 0.95 to 1. But it displayed like transforming from 1 to 1.05.

Comment: well, my guess was that the previous transformation collided somehow with the current.. although that should not be the case..

Comment: ill take another look at it a bit later

Comment: I found the way to fix it. Just move the `fromView.transform = .identity` to the completion block of `UIView.animate`. Thanks for the hint.